# Vehicle Routing in python to solve with Gurobi - i struggle with the objective function for a three index formulation (quicksum method)

Tags: gurobi

My problem is, I recently got into python and I did a two index flow formulation already - if someone is interested in the code, just let me know.

Now i dont know how to give the quicksum method quicksum 3 variables - anyone has a clue how to code the objective function? so how to give it the i,j and the k

Just look at the objective function of the picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf3ch.jpg

for example if i do it `vor c[i,j] and x[i,j]` it looks like this `(quicksum(x[i, j]*c[i, j] for i, j in A))`

Now i tried to adapt and integrated the k like this : `mdl.setObjective(quicksum(c[i,j]*x[i,j,k] for i,j in A) for k in K)`

I'm struggling with it for 5 days now and I am trying to solve this problem with phyton and gurobi - but it wont let me introduce 3 variables - most of the time I get a

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing error. The two index version works just fine
```

- maybe i need to integrate the one quicksum into the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

The [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) needs to be inside the quicksum function:

```
mdl.setObjective(quicksum(c[i,j]*x[i,j,k] for i,j in A for k in K))
```

Comment: If i try this i still get an error - still unexpected EOF while parsing error

Comment: somehow i got this error now KeyError: (0, 1, 1) - does someone know whats wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

So i tried introcuing vrp related variables in the dic - also didnt work

i will just post the complete code here now - the 2 index version is working on the left side

the three index version on the right is not wokring at all

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Je3W.jpg